# Outlook 2010: permanently change all reply-to's for an outlook profile

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, reply

At the place I work we are wanting to have all student worker email accounts automatically have a 'reply-to' field pointing to our global inbox. In other words, we want all incoming mail to go to global_inbox@example.com but allow all student workers to send email from their work account (eg joesmoe@example.com).

I know that when composing a new email, I can choose options > "direct reply to" and that does what I want except that it has to be done manually and is therefore one more step which might be forgotten from time to time.

How can we set up an outlook profile and/or email-account to have a specific reply-to *by default*?

**Additional context (if needed):**

The reason we don't want students to have access to the global inbox is because they will mistakingly make decisions which are incorrect based off of some emails (like who to assign certain problems to). So we want the staff to read through the inbox and make those decisions so that the students don't mistakingly make wrong decisions.

However, the student workers do need to send email to clients to do their job, so they can send email via their work account, but...

Sometimes students forget to check their work email for weeks, so replies get lost :(. That is why we want all reply-to fields to go to global_inbox@example.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also have to use Outlook, for me it worked with [a small VBA macro](http://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/outlook-always-use-reply-to-return-mail-for-free/):

1. In Outlook open your Visual Basic Editor (+ or Extras → Macro → Visual Basic Editor)
2. I did this in german, so the names may vary a bit: In Project1 (VbaProject.OTM) open Microsoft Office Outlook Objects → ThisOutlookSession
3. Enter the following Code:

   ```
   Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

   'add reply-To address
   Item.ReplyRecipients.Add "office@example.com"
   Item.ReplyRecipients.ResolveAll   
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you setup a rule for each student worker where replies are forwarded to the other in box? It could probably be setup with the following rules:

- check Messages as they arrive

  - where my name is in the To box
  - with specific words ("RE") in the subject

This should do what you want, assuming that I'm reading the question correctly. I admit that it goes about it in a completely different way.

The only other option I can think of is to change the default template. I found a way to create your own template, but not how to turn it into the default.

http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/create-use-email-templates-in-outlook-2010/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Fill the address you want to use to `Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Email -> [select your email address] -> Change -> Advanced options -> Reply to`.